# How to find Latitudes and Longitudes of projections of the vertices of a rectangular plane below earth's surface?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I want to find out the latitudes and longitudes of projections of the vertices of a rectangular plane inside the earth's surface. I know dimensions of rectangle, angles of orientation and latitude and longitude of the projection of the center of the rectangle. Earth's curvature is also to be considered

I added an Image which is a 2D representation of what i want. The plane actually is having 2 angles (its trace makes an angle 'A' with North and the plane makes an angle 'B' with the horizontal). I want to find lat longs of all 4 projections

Note: The dimensions shown are just for depiction. they are not to scale

[image]

Comment: I suspect that what you are asking would become a lot clearer with a diagram.

Comment: How far are you from the surface and how precise do you need to be ? Considering the radius of the Earth (6370km), if you are only a few km deep this will not markedly affect the Lat/Long (5km-> 10-4). If you want an precise solution, you need to decide weither your rectangle is supposed to be a plane or to follow the Earth curvature.

Comment: Im dealing with fault planes which are only a few km deep. So I suppose a plane rectangle would do. Im finding it difficult to calculate lat longs..so plz help!

Comment: i added a 2D representation to make it clear...hope it will help u to understand

Comment: Exactly how is the plane supposed to be projected? Some natural possibilities include (1) a central projection, (2) computation of the (lat, lon) coordinates of the vertices, and (3) a projection in a specified direction (which seems to be what the figure is depicting). Please don't ask us to guess: edit this question to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Use XYZ coordinate system with origin at centre of the earth.  Convert lat/long of the centre of the rectangle to XYZ.  Then use 3D trigonometry to compute XYZ coordinates of the vertices.  Finally, convert your XYZ coordinates back to lat/long.  Procedure for doing the lat/long to XYZ conversion can be found here:   www.ngs.noaa.gov/TOOLS/XYZ/xyz.shtml